# Finding the latest iOS version number

Tags: ios, versions

Is there a public API that can provide me with the most recent iOS version number? I need to be able to programmatically query the most recent version number in a reliable way (so no web scraping). Is this possible?

Comment: Selenium browser automation could be used to get the content of release notes page of Apple or Wikipedia, which also has consistent site structure.  Curl etc would be downloading, as you said, you don’t want it.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Any solution requires downloading, the challenge is in finding a source with an easy to parse and long-time stable structure.

Comment: As the question is more about finding a source than parsing it's content in whatever programming language used it's IMHO on-topic.